# Error occurs while using the db module in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

I'm making a game in python using `pygame`. I have installed dependencies such as `Ship` and `db`.
However, while running the python file I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a_invasion.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ship import Ship
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ship\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import db, config, load
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\db\__init__.py", line 69
    print "var", var
              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("var", var)?
```

Comment: Could you post your code in "a_invasion.py"?

Comment: The `db` module does was designed for python 2 and doesn't look like it was modified for python 3. You can either change line 69 in `site-packages\db\__init__.py` to `print("var", var)` and address any other problems if they come up or look for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It may be some dependency conflicts. Check the Python version the libraries are using.

If I do `print "ok"`, it works with Python 2 but Python 3.* will complaint:

```
print 'ok'
      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('ok')?
```